# Python requests: chunked post request

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, chunked-encoding

I am trying to send a post request through the request module with `headers["Transfer-encoding"] = "chunked"`, but I am getting back:

`<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Content Length</h2><hr><p>HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.</p>`

I am sending a json string. `headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"` is also given.
Does anybody know if I am missing some setting? Maybe I should set the chunk-size somewhere?

Analysing the headers of the request attached to the response I actually get a content-length header different from zero.

I also tried to create a custom generator from the json string, and pass it to the post method as `data=`, but it it seems to simply hang there (also above the given `timeout=`).

Answer (score 4):

Your error says you didn't create the request properly (it's 4xx error, not 5xx which would indicate server issue).
`Transfer-Encoding: chunked` serves for sending data in chunks. When the body of your message consists of unspecified number of chunks and you send them in lets say - stream. I would suggest reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Each chunk should have it's size in front of the data. For instance:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/plain 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

9\r\n
Some data\r\n 
6\r\n
Python\r\n
```

If you want to send chunked requests with python requests module. You probably need a generator method for that. Please see [this](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests). With such few information I can't help you more.